# why does FlatList keep loading forever?

Tags: react-native

I am using FlatList to write an infinite scroll, but it keeps sending request to my server forever.  please see the code blow. I don't find any article clarify when the next page will load,  what exactly does the `onEndReached` will be triggered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadOrders } from '../redux/modules/Order';
import OrderListItem from './OrderListItem';
import { forOwn, isEmpty, reduce } from 'lodash';

class OrderList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      page: 1,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
       this.loadOrders();
  }

  loadOrders = () => {
    const { page } = this.state;

    AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken")
    .then((value) => {
         return  `Bearer ${value}`;
    })
    .then((userToken) => {
      return this.props.loadOrders(page, { Authorization: userToken });
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        error: response.error || null,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error});
    })
    ;
  }

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.loadOrders();
  };

  onPressItem = (id: string) => {

  };

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => `order-item-${item.id}`;

  renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <OrderListItem
      order={item}
      onPressItem={this.onPressItem}
    />
  );

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };


  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.props.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { orders} = this.props;

    if (orders.length> 0) {
      return (
      <View containerStyle={styles.container} >
        <FlatList
          data={orders}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
      </View>
    );
    }

    return <View>
      <Text>empty</Text>
    </View>
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  },
  item: {
    padding: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc'
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  let order = state.get('order').toJS();

  return {
    orders: isEmpty(order.entities) ? [] : reduce(order.entities, (result, value) => {
      result.push({ key: value.id, ...value });

      return result;
    }, []),
    loading: order.loading
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadOrders
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderList);
```

[image: if] the `if` part is false , but the onEndReached methods is still called, I must be insane.

the 
[image: _maybeCallOnEndReached]

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
```

to this:

```
 onEndReachedThreshold={0}
```

Right now you're calling the end reached when you're halfway through. You can also try adding this to the FlatList:

```
legacyImplementation = {true}
```

If this still won't work I would recommend doing the 'pull' onRefresh. A nice example for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHLFJs7jlI4

Answer (score 0):

i met the problem too, in my case:

renderFooter somethings render null(height: 0) when loaded, but render ActivityIndicator when loading, and ActivityIndicator has its heigth bigger than 0(null's height)

**when heigth change from 0 to ActivityIndicator's height, it will call onEndReached again**

and you say **the if part is false**, i think its because **it's not really false**。

when code really run in FlatList, the `if` part is true, so it call onEndReached, and then the `_scrollMetrics.contentLength` or `this._sentEndForContentLength` has changed **for some reason** before your console in chrome. **which makes the `if` part return false**

above is all my thought for now, and i am still debugging for this problem,  hope this answer will help you all